# Visual Studio 2012 Default Debug IE Browser Version

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging

Details first: using VS2012, IE10, Windows 8, IIS 7.5 express, ASP.NET webforms application.

Problem: when I debug an ASP.NET web forms application, IE10 opens as expected but it's under IE10 compatibility mode using IE7 document standards. I would rather this did not happen as I have to remember to open the developer tools and change the browser version used in debugging. And plenty of times I have forgotten, assumed the layout and CSS is correct then remember sometime later to check that setting and find out everything is broken in non-IE7 versions.

It's rather frustrating and I cannot find any configuration files or settings within IE10 and VS2012 to change this. And I cannot find any configuration files for IIS 7.5 at all. And, in fact, I tried the VS2012 development server and it opens IE10 the same way, so most likely not an IIS express issue.

I should note: IE10 opens in non-compatibility mode for normal browsing. It only defaults this way in debugging web applications from VS2012.

Anybody know how to change this default setting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

1. Open IE
2. Press `Alt` and click `Tools` from IE menu bar
3. Select `Compatibility View Settings`
4. Remove `localhost` from `Websites you added to Compatibility View`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `X-UA-Compatibility` meta tag to force IE to run as a particular version, generally speaking you want to force it to `edge`, which forces it to run as the standards version:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

You can learn more about the [meta tag here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: OK, that's all fine and good. But generally, while debugging only, there is no way to specify which version I want to run as a default?
Here is another example: I opened a new version of IE10 and it was in standard IE10. I copied the localhost url for debugging into it and it changed to compliant with IE7 standards.
I'm guessing this has to do with the localhost now, so maybe that is the issue?
I do not have IIS installed on this machine. Only using IIS Express that comes bundled with VS2012.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how IE tracks when to "remember" version modes but I believe it is a) per-session when changed with the dev tools or b) determined by the `x-au-compatible` meta tag or c) by the doctype (or lack-there-of which forces quirks mode).

Comment: This is a good solution and it's also possible to target specific versions of IE by changing the content attribute in the meta tag to  "IE=EmulateIE8" or "IE=8" for instance.